# Expression Language Symfony Component - cannot validate empty string

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I tried to play around Expression Language in validation, and I found something strange.

Let's consider Dog model

```
class Dog
{

    /**
     * @Assert\Expression("this.getName() != 'aa' ", message="Not good!")
     */
    private $name = 'aa';
    ...
}
```

'aa' != 'aa' => false so validation service reports error - cool,
but lets try to do the same with

```
class Dog
{

    /**
     * @Assert\Expression("this.getName() != '' ", message="Not good!")
     */
    private $name = '';
    ...
}
```

This one does not return any error during validation??? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I've found line that you can be interested by :)

line 47, *vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/ExpressionValidator.php*

```
if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
  return;
}
```